# Yii CHtml::ajaxLink not working

Tags: php, ajax, yii

In my Yii application I need to create a ajax link for a controller action. But when I click the link it  is remaining in the same page.

What may be the error?
My code  snippet.

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
    $text = 'Click me', 
    $url = Yii::app()->createUrl('consumerRequest/manage' )



    ); ?>
```

I am unable to trace the source of error, is it in the logic itself or syntax ?   anybody kindly help me.

Comment: This might help a bit: http://lostmahbles.com/simple-yii-ajaxlink/

Comment: You can just look at the resulting JS and HTML in the source code. What code does it output? Are there any JS errors in your console and when you click the link what happens, are there any requests in the requests tab of your developer tools?

Comment: no I checked the console .it is not showing any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the assignments:

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
    'Click me', 
     Yii::app()->createUrl('consumerRequest/manage' )
); ?>
```

Comment: What do you have in the output html?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
    $text = 'Click me', 
    $url = Yii::app()->createUrl('consumerRequest/manage'),//ajaxURL
    array(),
    array( //htmlOptions
        'href' => Yii::app()->createUrl('consumerRequest/manage'),//targetURL
    )
); ?>
```

or:

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
    $text = 'Click me', 
    $url = Yii::app()->createUrl('consumerRequest/manage'),//ajaxURL
    array(
        'data' => array(),
        'type'      => 'POST',
        'success'   => 'js:function(html){
            window.location.href = '.Yii::app()->createUrl('consumerRequest/manage').';//targetURL
         }'
    )
); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

And what are you going to do with the ajax results? Read this detail first.

[`CHtml::ajaxLink`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajaxLink-detail)

Comment: The page will not change unless you ask it to. Ajax works in the background to fetch requested results/html/files from server and does something to the page (or keep in memory or do something else like request more dependent information). You need to code it using javascript/jquery - otherwise nothing would happen :(

Answer (score 0):

CHtml::ajaxLink() will make a asynchronous call to the target page. So, your page does not move to anywhere.

If you are looking to process the data which is coming from ajaxLink(). Try like this

```
    <?php
    echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
            'Click me', 
            Yii::app()->createUrl('consumerRequest/manage'),
            array
            (
                'success' => 'js:function(data)'
                . '{'
                . 'alert(data);'
                . '//Do what ever you want here'
                . '}'
            )

    );
    ?>
```

You can make the direct like as bellow

```
    <a href="<?=Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('consumerRequest/manage');?>">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya I found  the   solution , I had to use div tag properly , the code snippet is correct